# last() and [] operator give different results

Tags: python, django

I have a model RSSFeed.
To get the last element in my DB, I do:

```
RSSFeed.objects.last()
# Output: <RSSFeed: www.sooperarticles.com>
```

I slice it to get the first 10 element in the query

```
first_ten_feeds = RSSFeed.objects.all()[:10]
```

Using first and the bracket operator is consistent:

```
first_ten_feeds.first()
# Output: <RSSFeed: pressetext News>
first_ten_feeds[0]
# Output: <RSSFeed: pressetext News>
```

But using last and the bracket operator is not consistent:

```
first_ten_feeds[9]
# Output: <RSSFeed: FinanzNachrichten.de: Nachrichten zu IT-Dienstleistungen>

first_ten_feeds.last()
# Output: <RSSFeed: www.sooperarticles.com>
```

Why? I expect to get the same result for last() and [] above.

`RSSFeed.objects.last()` and `first_ten_feeds.last()` seem to give the same result but that does not make sense to me.

Comment: Django gives AssertionError as it Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken. Don't know why you are not getting it.

Comment: @IshwarJangid where have you seen a reorder ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers  calling the `last` will do reorder by `-pk` key if none has been applied before https://github.com/django/django/blob/75d627888bf42f8de6064a0bd665c98c0df66c55/django/db/models/query.py#L645.

Comment: @Take_Care_ indeed, I just saw this - so the answer to Ishwar is: because his model defines a default ordering.

Comment: With Django 2.1.5, for models without default ordering, I get `Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken` for both `first()`and `last()`. For models with default ordering, `first()` works, `last()` gives an error. So I cannot replicate the behavior above with the available information. Can you show us the RSSFeed model? What's your Django version?

Comment: I use Django 1.1. I think its not important how the model looks like since I encounter this behaviour for every model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the code actually. `QuerySet.last()` is defined as

```
    for obj in (self.reverse() if self.ordered else self.order_by('-pk'))[:1]:
        return obj
```

and what `QuerySet.reverse()` basically does is to return a clone of the queryset [with the direction of the `order by` clause reverted](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L1085), so basically instead of

```
SELECT (...) from yourmodel ORDER BY somefield ASC LIMIT 10
```

the SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT (...) from yourmodel ORDER BY somefield DESC LIMIT 10
```

so `first_ten_feeds.last()` will actually returns the same thing as `RSSFeed.objects.last()`.

This behaviour [doesn't really match the doc](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/ref/models/querysets.html#last) and is quite surprising, not to say totally unexpected, and I strongly suggest you fill in a bug report on django's issue tracker - either it's the expected behaviour (for the django devs at least) and then it should be clearly documented, or it's a plain bug.

Comment: Hm interesting that I am the first one who encounters this "bug" because last() is actually a really basic thing.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit suprised too actually. OTHO  using both slicing and `last` together might not that common either - I obviously never did at least (else I would certainly have found this out), and I've worked on dozens of Django projects...

Comment: One reason it might not be so common is that it gives an error for most people :). Specifically, `reverse()` and therefore `last()` is forbidden for sliced querysets. What Django version did you get this to work with?

Comment: @EndreBoth I almost often specify a default sort for my models so I don't get the "sliced queryset/ordering" issue.

Comment: See my comment on the question about the default sort.

Comment: @EndreBoth still stuck with 1.11 atm.

Comment: Then it seems the bug has been fixed; there is probably a related ticket in Django's issue system somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just crossed with this question, I have a similar case:

```
 elem = my_qs.last()
 elem in my_qs
>>> False
 elem
>>> <1 - 'elem 1'>    # <- wrong
 elem = list(my_qs)[-1]
 elem
>>> <2 - 'elem 2'>    # <- correct
```

Still don't know the reason for this.

I also tried to apply some ordering, as suggested for later versions of Django, but the result is the same.

```
elem = my_qs.all().order_by('pk').last()
elem
>>> <1 - 'elem 1'>
```